# Can time machine be set to store local backups for more than 24h?

Tags: time-machine

I realise that using an internal drive as time machine drive (especially your main drive) does not give you protection against loss of the machine or failure of the disk, but occasionally when travelling without an external time machine drive (which allbeit I now try to keep with me) I wondered if it is possible to set time machine to store local backups for more than 24h -- say, 7 days, given plenty of disk space being available on the local main drive, which I generally have.

Comment: I can't tell about other versions, but I am using Catalina and local time machines backups fills my disk for about the 10 last days. I check it by using the command `tmutil listlocalsnapshotdates`.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I ran that command on High Sierra and it gives me just the past 24h.

Comment: it depends on the MacOS version, some versions are storing the defaul which is 1day, but Mojave and Catalina I know it can fill the disk